# How to add a launch screen page to an Android app from apk editor?

Tags: android, apk, addition, launcher, launch-screen

I want to learn how to add an image as a launcher screen to an apk that can perform a simple activity like starting the app from a push of a botton and maybe add a couple nots and links in that page.
It would be appreciated if you can guide me how to do it in apk editor or a simple way of doing it I'm not a pro.

I tried using pre created patches but no Matter what patche i try or on what apk i use it will always be errors.

Comment: Android apps don't have a launcher screen by default. If an app shows a screen while loading in background then this is just a regular activity and how to change that activity depends on how the app was implemented (via XML, Jetpack Compose, or if the app uses a framework like react native, Xamarin, Flutter, ...).

Comment: I mean I can't just add a step in codes to have a page before the loading screen? And then after that with a botton triggers the loading screen and launch the app and so on

Comment: You can but modifying an existing app would mean to use [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) for decompilation, then modify the sources and afterwards recompile. And apktool decompiles to smali code, not Java or Kotlin code. Coding a single method call is already a pain in Smali, don't want to know how difficult adding a whole Activity and integrating it into the app would be.

Comment: Then is there a way to modify an apk and adding an activity with java or kotlin? Is there any app to work with java or kotlin? Even on pc would be fine I'll find my way around